# Modifying JQuery code

Tags: jquery, getjson

I have an app with >> 50 calls to $.getJSON("...", function(data) {...} );
At the start we didn't need to worry about handling callback failures.
Now we do occassionally chain a .error()  to the end of the JSON call.  This works fine.
Now we have decided it best to do this for every call.  Is there any way to tweak JQuery so that I can have the .error() chained to the end of every call with some default error handling as opposed to having to modify every .js file I have that uses this method?

Thanks .... J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajaxSetup:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

With this method you will be able to set global jquery ajax options.

Answer (score 0):

You can set defaults for your AJAX calls with `.ajaxSetup()`, but to set a default error handler use `.ajaxError()`.

To run this for errors on all AJAX requests, attach it to `document`

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError){
    console.error('An AJAX error occurred');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/